# Washer outlet extension after adding wall tile

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, pipe, washer

This is the washer hot and cold water before I added tiles

[image]

After I installed tiles, the connection was flushed to the tile so I had to add an extension

[image]

To me, this is an ugly hack because it makes the whole thing sticking out 5" from the wall (waste of space). The best ideal option would be an outlet box recessed but that was too late!

What are my options:

1. Leave it as-is and waste 5"
2. Cut a hole on tile, make a mess and do recessed back. This will require access in the back which is a closet room. I also need a plumber to do this.
3. Find something else that only makes it sticking out 2-3". Save 2"!
4. OTHERS?

I hope to hear any additional options.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your home store or a plumbing supply store for a greater selection, and pick up the right size pipe nipple. They come in many standard sizes and can even be custom made at some store. Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I got the shortest one: 2”. I am wondering if there is a different design

Comment: Keep looking... they make them smaller... did you try a plumbing store.